# Blackberry App not working on BIS

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-push

My BlackBerry App sends a message to the server over a webservice.
The server communicates by replying or sending a message to a web service.
The web service routes the message received from the server back to the BlackBerry App as a Push message.

I have registered for push Message but I don't know how to use this push Service in Eclipse.

Can anybody help on this ?

Comment: check my blog - http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/search/label/Push%20Notification

Comment: @Signare Mate you saved my day or I should says days :) thanks for your great tutorial I will try this if I found any error I will ask you I hope it is ok with you  :)

Comment: @Signare Hi mate i just dont want to use push Message i just want to verify my app on Blackberry server so that it can work on BIS the connection url i have user for it is like https://192.168.10.**/Service.asmx;deviceside=true  I just want my app to be verified by BB Server and does not stop me to hitting my webservice

Comment: @Signare Or It should bypass Blackberry server anything likt this